# Basics of running multiple internal ruby/rails apps on an IIS server - is something like passenger required for this situation?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, windows, iis, deployment

I am going to be deploying  about a dozen rails apps on an IIS server. These apps are behind out firewall for internal use only. They will all be low usage but critical apps.

The current setup is

- IIS running on server 2012
- Rails 4 is running on iis installed via the webplatforminstaller.
- We will be using MS sql server
- Apps uploaded from the laptop to the server do run.
- There will be about 15 apps running. We can add another server if necessary.
- Nothing else will be running on that server
- E.g. an app might be located in c:\inetpub\wwwroot\apps\sales  and another in \hr. etc.

  What I've read about deploying multiple rails apps seems to be geared toward public facing sites. I don't see much about private sites using a server ip/folder setup

Question:
 - Can multiple apps be run without adding a tool such as passenger?

Comment: Um, Passenger is a Linux/Unix application which works with nginx or Apache and won't do you any good on IIS. If I had any choice whatsoever I would choose not to deploy on IIS/MsSQL. There are very few rails shops that do and the adapters etc are not in the ballpark of what is available for Unix/Postgres/outside the MS box. Lots of headaches - very few benefits.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible using the IIS `HttpPlatformHandler` extension. [Scott Hanselman did a good write up on it](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/AnnouncingRunningRubyOnRailsOnIIS8OrAnythingElseReallyWithTheNewHttpPlatformHandler.aspx) that explains how to use it.

Although, in that blog post it's suggested to use `JRuby` and `Tomcat`. I don't think that is necessary, however I would suggest using `puma` as your webserver.

Comment: Thanks- I got it running with a combo of Puma and Jruby.